# HashiCorp Vault: Generate Certificate and Key: What is the format for time-to-live (ttl)?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

HashiCorp Vault REST API has an endpoint to generate (signed) cert and key: `/pki/issue/:name`

Official docs: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/secret/pki#generate-certificate-and-key

In the body of the request, there is a JSON object key `"ttl"` for time-to-live.  What are the supported value formats for this key?

I cannot find supported formats in official docs.  By luck, I found other examples that allow suffices `"h"` for hours, e.g., `"360h"`, and `"d"` for days, e.g., `"7d"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expects a time duration string parsable by Go `time.ParseDuration`.

https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/1195

https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseDuration